# iPhone Audio Streaming

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, audio-streaming, audiostreamer

I would like to know how to start creating an Audio Streaming Player to iPhone (a radio streaming).

I read that I have to use AudioToolbox and AudioQueue. Is there any easy solution? Anybody has an advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/03/streaming-mp3aac-audio-again.html for a very complete audio streaming example.

Comment: Thank you. I've seen this post before, but the code doesn't work with all kind of streaming. Also, my doubt is also if today there is any easier way to do it, but it seems that no.

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of the iOS SDK allow you to use AVPlayer which can also play remote mp3 audio streams. AVPlayer is easier to use and way more high-level than the AudioQueue API.